# is it possible to only recieve cookies on a particular route, rather than all the routes?

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, access-token, refresh-token

I'm implementing an auth service, where I'm using the concept of access and refresh token. Storing refresh token as httponly cookie on the client side. I want to ask, how can i make only certain api routes to have cookie in their req. like, the refresh JWT token should only be sent over /auth/refresh route only.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies have these options to control when they are sent, which you can set when creating them:

- Domain: auth.mycompany.com
- Path: /auth/refresh

So it is really a sesign question to structure server routes accordingly. Cookies cannot support multiple paths.

Generally OAuth cookies are sent from front channel requests (browser redirects) and not used for back channel requests (Ajax calls) where the browser is likely to drop them anyway.

I would avoid building to an Auth server yourself - it is a complex component - aim to use a free system such as [Curity Community Edition](https://curity.io/product/community/) or [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Gary ! Right now I'm just using a hack whether to include cookie in header or not.  By adding  ` {  withCredentials: true } ` in axios. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Nor really since security should be decided server side - I added a couple more points to my answer ..

Comment: i think then setting path solves the problem, browser will only send httponly token to that route. Im learning architecture side of auth, thats why im implementing it by myself. thanks for sharing the free systems. Ill try them as well.